# wxPython: ProgressDialog crash

Tags: python, wxpython

I have this program that establishes a connection. When it's trying to connect it creates a ProgressDialog. When the connection fails it should cleanly close the ProgressDialog, but it doesn't, it segfaults.

Here is a reduced example of the code in question. You can replicate this behaviour by running this script and press enter several times, which will click the only button in the app and trigger the code to try a connection.

I could only figure out so far that the app only crashes when the line 53:'print('after_pulse')' doesn't run, which would indicate there is something wrong with the 'Pulse' call, but I can't figure out what.

Does anyone know what's making this code crash?

If not, can you at least replicate this behaviour?

Specs:

Ubuntu 12.04

Python 2.7.3

wxPython 2.8.12.1

Edit: Much smaller example program with no twisted code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''test2'''

import wx   # Must be imported before any other wx modules


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='TestFrame')
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label='test')
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_handler)
        self.button.SetFocus()

    def button_handler(self, event):
        pd_style = wx.PD_APP_MODAL|wx.PD_CAN_ABORT|wx.PD_SMOOTH
        self.pd = wx.ProgressDialog('test_title', 'test_msg', parent=self,  
                                    style=pd_style)
        self.pd.SetFocus()

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(1000/60, False)

        wx.CallAfter(self.err_connection)

    def on_timer(self, event):
        print('before_pulse')
        cont, _skip = self.pd.Pulse()
        print('after_pulse')
        if not cont:
            self.err_connection()

    def err_connection(self):
        print('err_connection')
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.pd.Destroy()
        self.button.SetFocus()


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are destroying the progress dialog while it is still in the process of doing the last Pulse().  Sometimes some platforms will defer part of the processing of a particular API until later, after the first part has been done or whatever.  If you delay the call to Destroy you will probably have better results. Try:

```
wx.CallAfter(self.pd.Destroy)
```

Also, 60 times per second is awfully fast for things like updating UI elements.  That's much faster than the eye can see, and could be causing some events to stack up and handlers to be called in unexpected orders, like getting a timer event and trying to do a Pulse() after the dialog has been destroyed.  Try 10 or 20 times per second instead.

Comment: I tried using wx.CallAfter(self.pd.Destroy) but the behaviour remained the same. I run Pulse 60 times/s to make the Pulse animation smooth, just specifying wx.PD_SMOOTH doesn't quite cut it. I tried reducing the amount of Pulses/s though and it worked, with both 10 and 20, any higher and I get the same behaviour.

Comment: About the possibility that this behaviour might be caused by the delayed Destroy(). I have tried a few changes and the app behaves in a way that seems to both support and exclude that possibility. I tried checking if the ProgressDialog is active when the time event handler runs, and when the app crashes the PD is never active. On the other hand I also Stop() the timer just before the Destroy() and the timer goes immediately into a stopped state, I can check with isRunning, and I found every time the timer handler runs the timer is not stopped, which would imply the Destroy() didn't run yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found ShowModal() is required, e.g.

```
dlg = wx.ProgressDialog(title, msg, maximum=100)
dlg.ShowModal()
dlg.Update(0, "Please Wait...")
...
dlg.Destroy()
```

Without ShowModal(), the app would crash the next time it tried to show another progress dialog.